# $n>1$, $p_n$ is the prime number nth then $p_{n+1}^{n^2} > p_n^{n^2+1}$ (conjecture)

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $p_n$ is prime number nth:

If n>1 then: $$p_{n+1}^{n^2} > p_n^{n^2+1}$$

I checked the conjecture above true for [first fifty million primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/).

> Could You give your remark, reference, or your proof of conjecture above?

Comment: Is the difference between the two numbers usually large?

Comment: Yes, they are very very  large. So I check by logarith two sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$p_{n+1}^{n^2} > p_n^{n^2+1}$
is the same as
$p_{n+1} 
\gt p_n^{1+1/n^2}
=p_n\cdot p_n^{1/n^2}
$.

Since
$p_n
\approx n \ln n$,

$\begin{array}\\
p_n^{1/n^2}
&\approx (n \ln n)^{1/n^2}\\
&=e^ {\ln(n \ln n)/n^2}\\
&=e^ {(\ln n+\ln \ln n)/n^2}\\
&<e^ {2\ln n/n^2}\\
&\approx 1+2\ln n/n^2\\
\text{so}\\
p_n\cdot p_n^{1/n^2}
&<p_n\cdot (1+2\ln n/n^2)\\
&=p_n+2p_n\ln n/n^2\\
&\approx p_n+2(n \ln n)\ln n/n^2\\
&= p_n+2\ln^2 n/n\\
&< p_n+1
\qquad\text{for large } n\\
\end{array}
$

since
$\ln^2 n/n
\to 0$.

If your original inequality is
$p_{n+1}^{n} > p_n^{n+1}
$,
this becomes
$p_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)} > p_n^{1/n}
$
which contradicts
Firoozbakht's
conjecture
(see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Conjectures_about_gaps_between_primes
for this and other conjectures).

Comment: Interestingly, replace $n^2+1$ with $(n+1)^2$ and it becomes equivalent to the negation of Cramér's conjecture.

Comment: Can you send me a link states that:  $p_n
\approx n \ln n$, ?

Comment: That is called the prime number theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: @DanBrumleve :)